# How do I convert xml.gz format to JSON?

Tags: node.js, json, xml, express

I'm new to xml and I need to make a get request to an endpoint to get some data. There's quite a large amount of data and it's being sent back in xml.gz format. Is there a way for me to change this to JSON on my node server?

Sorry if this doesn't make sense, I'm too new to this to even know if this question is right.

Comment: XML has different semantics than JSON, if you would try to convert it perfectly then you'd get an unnecessarily complex structure as a result. It would make more sense to operate on the XML document directly.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to uncompress the .gz file, and this will give you an XML file.

There are many tools that will convert XML to JSON and they all give different results, because there is no right way of doing it. So it rather depends on whether you want the data in a specific JSON format, or whether any old JSON will do.

Comment: do you know how to uncompress the .gz file in node/express? I can't find a way to do it

Comment: Not offhand, I would need to research it.

Comment: Alright no worries, I keep running into countless dead ends with this, been trying to solve it for hours now